# Regular Expression filtering all translation functions

Tags: php, regex, gettext, poedit

I am working on a Webinterface that provides the same function like poEdit.

I want to walk trough all .php files in a specified folder and search every line for a translation. For this I would like to use regular expression searching the actual line in the php file and return the translation-text-parameter and the domain-parameter.

My function looks like this:

```
__('This is my translation', 'domain');
```

But because for the domain-parameter I defined a default, the function __() can also be called like this:

```
__('this is my translation');
```

Now in PHP i tried to use the Function preg_match_all() but i can't gent my regex together.

Here is an example of a possible line in the script and the output array I would like to receive with the preg_match_all() function:

```
echo __('Hello World'); echo __('Some domain specific translation', 'mydomain');
```

Array output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello World
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some domain specific translation.
            [1] => mydomain
        )
)
```

Can anyone help me out with the Regex and the preg_math_all() flags?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Just to clarify - you are looking to remove the 2nd parameter from **all** of the __() function calls ?

Comment: You should probably avoid naming a function __ iirc names of functions, classes etc starting with __ are considered reserved for php developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Array shift needed, because zero element will always contain full match, there is no flag to exclude it AFAIK.

```
if(preg_match_all('/__\(\s*\'((?:[^\']|(?<=\\\)\')+)\'(?:\s*,\s*\'((?:[^\']|(?<=\\\)\')+)\')?\s*\)/us', $data, $result)) {
  foreach ($result as &$item) {
    array_shift($item);
  }
  unset($item);
  var_dump($result);
}
```

It finds correctly calls like these __('lorem \' ipsum', 'my\'domain'). It would fail on __('lorem \\') though.

Comment: The regex itself does exactly what i need if i paste it in a regex tester but if i try to implement your code in my php, i get following error:

`Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 25`.

Any Idea?

Comment: @Spinnenzunge Are you using single or double quotes around regex string when you declare it in PHP? Are you using / as regex delimiter?

Comment: I copied/pasted exactly what you posted. Could solve the problem by adding an extra backslash on `(?<=\\)`.

Comment: Oh, exactly. Sorry, forgot about that one. Editing my answer now.

Comment: Additional question: What would i have to add, if i wanted to call the function parameters not only with single quotes but also with double quotes, like `__("This is my translation", "mydomain")` ?

Comment: @Spinnenzunge look into Tomalak's answer, it covers both cases. Or just find/replace all single quotes to double quotes in my example (including quotes limiting preg string) and run it for second time.

Comment: Ok, got it to run with both single and double quotes. Can I aks another thing? Is it also possible to catch an unescaped string like: `__('This is my "special" translation', 'domain');` ?

Answer (score 1):

The regex you would need for this is considerably complex.

```
__\(\s*(['"])((?:(?!(?<!\\)\1).)+)\1(?:,\s*(['"])((?:(?!(?<!\\)\3).)+)\3)?\s*\)
```

Matches would be in groups 2 and 4, for example

```
__('This is my translation', 'domain');
```

would produce these groups:

1. `'`
2. `This is my translation`
3. `'`
4. `domain`

and this

```
__('This is my \'translation\'', "domain");
```

would produce these groups:

1. `'`
2. `This is my \'translation\'`
3. `"`
4. `domain`

Comment: And I have forgotten double quotes. Shame on me.

Comment: @Nameless: But I see that great minds think alike. +1 for your regex. :)